# Query to return closest LineString given a Point

Tags: postgis, distance, linestring, nearest-neighbor, knn

I have a road lines data in a table with field 
roads(id SERIAL ,the_line geometry(LineString,4326))

suppose an accident occurs in a middle or at any location in that waterline i want to stop the entire waterline
so, given a location or coordinates(POINT(350205.805 148722.56)),  I need to find a roadline which is closest to that point. and return its start point and endpoint

```
 "SELECT id, ST_AsText(ST_StartPoint(the_line )) AS startpoint,ST_AsText(ST_EndPoint(the_line )) AS endpoint from roadlines where (some condition to get the closest roadline) close to 'POINT(350205.805 148722.56)'"
```

**POINT(350205.805 148722.56) WILL BE THE INPUT**

Comment: while this is quite similar to other *KNN* related questions *and* indeed a duplicate topic of the post stated as duplicate, I strongly recommend to use the query structure below instead.

Answer (score 0):

A *Nearest Neighbor* search with a single, constant comparator is fairly simple; order the table by distance and get the first row:

```
SELECT a.id,
       ST_StartPoint(rl.the_line) AS sp,
       ST_EndPoint(rl.the_line) AS ep
FROM roadlines AS rl
ORDER BY rl.the_line::geography <-> ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(350205.805 148722.56)', <your_srid>), 4326)::geography
LIMIT 1;
```

The tricky part is how to handle different projections and their units; transform your projected point (fill in  `<your_srid>`) to WGS84 to match the lines CRS, then cast both to `geography` to get a precise distance measurement based on meter (on a sphere).

The `<->` *KNN* operator makes efficient use of the spatial index on the `roadlines` geometry column.

---

If you intend to run a *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search between two tables (i.e. finding the closest line to each point in a second table, or vice versa), a `JOIN LATERAL` is the way to go. See [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/283797/93656) answer for the basic structure.