# Update points geometry while snapping them to nearest line

Tags: postgis, postgresql, proximity, snapping, knn

I have two tables in the PostGIS database - points and lines. And I want to update points geometry to snap them to line if they lay within a certain distance.

By now I managed to create a new table with snapped points which has only geometries. This works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(lines.geom, points.geom) as snapped_point
FROM lines
INNER JOIN points on ST_Dwithin(lines.geom, points.geom, 5)
ORDER BY points.id;
```

But what I really need is to update the existing table. So I try:

```sql
UPDATE points
SET geom =  
(SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(lines.geom, points.geom) as snapped_point
FROM lines
INNER JOIN points on ST_Dwithin(lines.geom, points.geom, 5)
ORDER BY points.id);
```

And it did not work. How do I put these two pieces together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `UPDATE` requires you to explicitly define the *one, single* return value to be put in place of each specified column value. To get only those, one usually wants to use a reference to the current row...and that's no problem, since the current row is available as record values to all statements in the `UPDATE` query.

Your sub-query, however, fetches the full table join (all records of each possible pair in the `JOIN`) and picks one at random (or likely the first row in the set).

Using the `points.id` as in @ziggys answer is indeed one way to refer to the updated row; however, in cases where more than one line is in the given proximity, there will be as many candidates in the result with a matching id.

Instead, better make sure you will always snap the point to the *closest* line in the given proximity (if proximity is actually needed at all?); running

```
UPDATE points
  SET  geom = (
    SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(lines.geom, points.geom)
    FROM lines
    -- WHERE ST_DWithin(points.geom, lines.geom, 5)
    ORDER BY lines.geom <-> points.geom
    LIMIT 1
  )
;
```

will order the `lines.geom` in proximity *by distance* to the updated `points.geom`, and limits the set to the closest one. This is highly efficient only with a spatial index in place on `lines.geom`!

---

This is commonly referred to as (spatial) *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search; more on the concept can be found e.g. here

- [How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362)
- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)

Comment: Ok but this work if a Closest Point already exists .Else you Update the geom to NULL! So this is not a good solution to replace a point if it find a candidate.

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten This fails only if `ST_DWithin` returns no matches. Without proximity limitation, the subquery will *always* return a nearest neighbor. Here, OP asks for proximity limitation. Handle this in a `WHERE` filter in the outer `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 5):

just put the select qry in a cte and add the id column and join to the update clause

```
with a as(SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(lines.geom, points.geom) as snapped_point,points.id id
FROM lines
INNER JOIN points on ST_Dwithin(lines.geom, points.geom, 5)
ORDER BY points.id)
UPDATE points
SET geom =  snapped_point from a where points.id=a.id
```