# Calculating shortest distance between two tables using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I am trying to calculate shortest distance from each point to polygon where `idfield` match and add the distance to a field in the point table:

[image]

For the two "A" points the distance is the same, which is incorrect. I understand why but not how to fix it. If I had only one A point, it would work.

```
update public.tbl2
SET dist = sub.dist
from (

select  tbl2.idfield,
        st_shortestline(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom) geom, 
        round(st_length(st_shortestline(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom))::numeric, 0) dist
from public.tbl1 , public.tbl2
where tbl1.idfield = tbl2.idfield
) sub
where sub.idfield = tbl2.idfield
```

Comment: Remember that an `UPDATE` is effectively a per-row operation; you can refer to the updated row in the whole statement, and filter accordingly. Use this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362 for performance, with an additional `WHERE` filter for `idfield` in the sub-query, and `ST_Distance` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: ...and one more concerning `UPDATE` statements with direct relevance to your use case https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365070/update-points-geometry-while-snapping-them-to-nearest-line/365091#365091

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including the geometry in the outer where condition like:

```
update public.tbl2
SET dist = sub.dist
from (

select  tbl2.idfield, tbl2.geom t2geom,
        st_shortestline(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom) geom, 
        round(st_length(st_shortestline(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom))::numeric, 0) dist
from public.tbl1 , public.tbl2
where tbl1.idfield = tbl2.idfield
) sub
where sub.idfield = tbl2.idfield AND sub.t2geom = tbl2.geom
```

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but while this does work, it is utterly inefficient. I urge everyone interested in this to get familiar with the concepts outlined in the links in my comments above (why yes, they are my own answers; but there are plenty others out there featuring the same principle), as well as the core structure of `UDPATE` statements.