# Query the distance to the nearest location through a join table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-distance

I'm looking to select the distance from a given location to the nearest location in a joining table, and order by it. In my use case I have a `listings` table which is joined to `locations` table through `listing_location`. The `locations` table has two columns for coordinate - `latitude` and `longitude` (both doubles).

```sql
SELECT 
  listings.*
  ST_Distance(ST_Point(?, ?), ST_ClosestPoint(:unsure:, ST_Point(?, ?)), FALSE) AS distance)
JOIN listing_location
  ON listing_location.listing_id = listings.id
JOIN locations
  ON locations.id = listing_location.location_id
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

The question marks would be bound to the `longitude` and `latitude` of the given location, but I'm unsure what to pass into `:unsure:` in order to select the joined locations. Am I missing something, or thinking about this problem in the wrong way? Is this problem solvable when my location data is stored as `latitude`/`longitude` double columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to utilize the [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) operator for index driven *(K) Nearest Neighbor* searches; this core PostgreSQL operator is extended in PostGIS to specifically use a (spatial) GIST index when in `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT ls.*,
       ST_Distance(ll.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), <SRID>)) AS dist
FROM   listings AS ls
JOIN   listing_location AS ll_r
  ON   ls.id = ll_r.listing_id
JOIN   locations AS ll
  ON   ll.id = ll_r.location_id
ORDER BY
       ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ll.longitude, ll.latitude), <SRID>) <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), <SRID>)
-- LIMIT <X>
;
```

---

**Notes:**

- to actually *use* and index, you need to *have one in place*; you have two options here

  - add a `GEOMETRY` column (e.g. named `geom`), which is the intended behavior in PostGIS

    ```
    ALTER TABLE locations
      ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY(<TYPE>, <SRID>)
    ;

    UPDATE locations
      SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), <SRID>)
    ;
    ```

    and

    ```
    CREATE INDEX ON locations
      USING GIST (geom)
    ;
    ```
  - create a *functional index* on the creation expression (yes, double brackets)

    ```
    CREATE INDEX ON locations
      USING GIST ( (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ll.longitude, ll.latitude), <SRID>)) )
    ;
    ```
- work correctly with a *geographic* `<SRID>`; consider that

  - longitudinal surface distance between two pairs of `longitude/latitude` is a function of the cosines of their latitudes, meaning that one degree of longitude has a different surface length at different latitudes
  - the above also implies that *degree* based distances are useless without the latitudinal context
  - PostGIS' `GEOMETRY` type treats geographic coordinates as in the *Cartesian* plane rather than on a sphere/spheroid, and returns the base unit of the given CRS from `ST_Distance` (which is *degree* for geographical reference systems)

  You can now either

  - project your coordinates to a suitable planar reference (*projection*), or
  - use the `GEOGRAPHY` type, which is designed to specifically tackle these issues and provide an easy interface for highly precise metrics on the geoidal surface - at the *slight* cost of performance due to the heavier calculations, and a smaller set of functions supporting it.

  With this in mind, and favouring the `GEOGRAPHY` type over projections, your query and index creation would look like (note the cast (`::`) to `GEOGRAPHY`):

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON locations
    USING GIST ( (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ll.longitude, ll.latitude), <SRID>)::GEOGRAPHY) )
  ;

  --

  SELECT ls.*,
         ST_Distance(ll.geom::GEOGRAPHY, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), <SRID>)::GEOGRAPHY) AS dist
  FROM   listings AS ls
  JOIN   listing_location AS ll_r
    ON   ls.id = ll_r.listing_id
  JOIN   locations AS ll
    ON   ll.id = ll_r.location_id
  ORDER BY
         ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ll.longitude, ll.latitude), <SRID>)::GEOGRAPHY <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), <SRID>)::GEOGRAPHY
  -- LIMIT <X>
  ;
  ```

  ---

  You can also decide to

  - add a `GEOMETRY` column as above
  - put a *functional index* in place using the cast to `GEOGRAPHY`

    ```
    CREATE INDEX ON locations
      USING GIST ( (geom::GEOGRAPHY) )
    ;
    ```
  - and again cast the geometry column to `GEOGRAPHY` in your queries *on-the-fly*

  This has the advantage in the long run, since most client applications have a hard time working with `GEOGRAPHY`.

---

**Extra Note:**

After large updates, including adding columns and indexes, make sure you run

```
VACUUM ANALYZE <table>;
```

to update the statistics for the query planner!

---

**Related:**

- [Is the Geometry(4326) an alias for Geography datatype?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367366/is-the-geometry4326-an-alias-for-geography-datatype/367374#367374)
- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing answer - thank you so much for going into so much detail here! I really appreciate the explanation behind indexing and using the proper geometry types.